# How to get current ImageName from Animation UIImageView?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, nsarray

I have animation `UIImageView` that have 15 images.

```
UIImage *imageOne=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
UIImage *imageTwo=[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
UIImage *imageThree=[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"];
UIImage *imageFour = [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"];
UIImage *imageFive = [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"];
UIImage *imageSix = [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"];
UIImage *imageSeven = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"];
UIImage *imageEight = [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"];
UIImage *imageNine = [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"];
UIImage *imageTen = [UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"];
UIImage *imageEleven = [UIImage imageNamed:@"11.png"];
UIImage *imageTwelve = [UIImage imageNamed:@"12.png"];
UIImage *imageThirteen = [UIImage imageNamed:@"13.png"];
UIImage *imageFourteen = [UIImage imageNamed:@"14.png"];
UIImage *imageFifty = [UIImage imageNamed:@"15.png"];



NSArray *arrayOfImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:imageOne,imageTwo,imageThree,imageFour,imageFive,imageSix,imageSeven,imageEight,imageNine,imageTen,imageEleven,imageTwelve,imageThirteen,imageFourteen,imageFifty, nil];

self.imgView.animationDuration = 50.0;
self.imgView.animationImages= arrayOfImages;

[self.imgView startAnimating];
```

Now i want to get the name of current image when touch on UIImageView.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if([touch view] == self.imgView)
    {
        if([self.imgView.image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]])
        {
            NSLog(@"1");
        }

        else if([self.imgView.image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"]])
        {
            NSLog(@"2");
        }
    }
}
```

Above code doesn't work. How can i do it?

Comment: Are you getting the imageview instance

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the current image from an image view that's animating using animationImages. You'll need to loop through your array of images using a timer, and just set the image in the timer's action method.